# easy_install pygame not working due to "linux/videodev.h: No such file or directory" error

Tags: 12.10, python

Trying to install `pygame` through `easy_install` in Ubuntu 12.10 and the errors it gives me this:

```
Continuing With "setup.py"
warning: no files found matching 'readme.txt'
no previously-included directories found matching '*/CVS'
no previously-included directories found matching '*/*/CVS'
src/mixer.c: In function ‘chan_set_volume’:
src/mixer.c:660:9: warning: variable ‘result’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-  variable]
In file included from /usr/include/python2.7/Python.h:8:0,
             from src/scrap.h:22,
             from src/scrap.c:30:
/usr/include/python2.7/pyconfig.h:1161:0: warning: "_POSIX_C_SOURCE" redefined [enabled by default]
In file included from /usr/include/stdio.h:28:0,
             from src/scrap.c:24:
/usr/include/features.h:215:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
In file included from src/scrap.c:59:0:
src/scrap_x11.c: In function ‘_get_data_as’:
src/scrap_x11.c:567:17: warning: pointer targets in assignment differ in signedness [-Wpointer-sign]
src/scrap.c: In function ‘initscrap’:
src/scrap.c:329:15: warning: variable ‘mod’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
In file included from src/_camera.c:36:0:
src/camera.h:42:32: fatal error: linux/videodev.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

and running `sudo ln -s /usr/include/linux/videodev2.h /usr/include/linux/videodev.h` gives:

```
Continuing With "setup.py"
warning: no files found matching 'readme.txt'
no previously-included directories found matching '*/CVS'
no previously-included directories found matching '*/*/CVS'
src/mixer.c: In function ‘chan_set_volume’:
src/mixer.c:660:9: warning: variable ‘result’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
In file included from /usr/include/python2.7/Python.h:8:0,
             from src/scrap.h:22,
             from src/scrap.c:30:
/usr/include/python2.7/pyconfig.h:1161:0: warning: "_POSIX_C_SOURCE" redefined [enabled by default]
In file included from /usr/include/stdio.h:28:0,
             from src/scrap.c:24:
/usr/include/features.h:215:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
In file included from src/scrap.c:59:0:
src/scrap_x11.c: In function ‘_get_data_as’:
src/scrap_x11.c:567:17: warning: pointer targets in assignment differ in signedness [-Wpointer-sign]
src/scrap.c: In function ‘initscrap’:
src/scrap.c:329:15: warning: variable ‘mod’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
In file included from src/camera.h:20:0,
             from src/camera_v4l2.c:22:
src/pygame.h:678:14: warning: ‘PyGAME_C_API’ defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
src/camera_v4l.c: In function ‘v4l_open_device’:
src/camera_v4l.c:29:29: error: storage size of ‘cap’ isn’t known
src/camera_v4l.c:30:23: error: storage size of ‘buf’ isn’t known
src/camera_v4l.c:51:24: error: ‘VIDIOCGCAP’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/camera_v4l.c:51:24: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for      each function it appears in
src/camera_v4l.c:63:26: error: ‘VIDIOCGMBUF’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/camera_v4l.c:30:23: warning: unused variable ‘buf’ [-Wunused-variable]
src/camera_v4l.c:29:29: warning: unused variable ‘cap’ [-Wunused-variable]
In file included from src/camera.h:20:0,
             from src/camera_v4l.c:20:
src/camera_v4l.c: At top level:
src/pygame.h:678:14: warning: ‘PyGAME_C_API’ defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: Too bad rep to add tags "easy_install" and "pygame"...

Answer (score 14):

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14026861/67022) provides the correct symlink. You need to remove the `/usr/include/linux/videodev.h` that you created -- it is linking to the wrong version of the header file.

> ```
> sudo apt-get install libv4l-dev
> cd /usr/include/linux
> sudo ln -s ../libv4l1-videodev.h videodev.h
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Pygame needs some dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev libsdl-image1.2-dev libsdl-mixer1.2-dev libsdl-ttf2.0-dev   libsdl1.2-dev libsmpeg-dev python-numpy subversion libportmidi-dev ffmpeg libswscale-dev libavformat-dev libavcodec-dev
```

If you dont want to install them, install the precompiled package:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pygame
```

Answer (score 2):

Is the version of pygame in the repositories ([python-pygame](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/python-pygame))
 too old? If not, you should try installing that first.

Otherwise, use [python-pip](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/python-pip) to install `pygame`:

```
sudo pip install pygame
```

<sup>[Why use pip over easy_install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220404/why-use-pip-over-easy-install)</sup>

Comment: Can I alternate between pip and easy_install in a virtualenv?