# Error installing pygame: "error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1"

Tags: gcc

So I've tried pretty much all the answers to similar questions I've been able to find, but I still haven't found a working solution. The complete info I get is:

```
(first_kivy_app)bemery94@bemery94-XPS-15-9530:~/Downloads/pygame-1.9.1release$ python setup.py install
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'pygame._camera' extension
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/include/SDL -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/_camera.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/_camera.o
In file included from src/_camera.c:36:0:
src/camera.h:42:32: fatal error: linux/videodev.h: No such file or directory
 #include <linux/videodev.h>
                            ^
compilation terminated.
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Does anyone know a solution?

Thanks you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [easy\_install pygame not working due to "linux/videodev.h: No such file or directory" error](http://askubuntu.com/questions/203630/easy-install-pygame-not-working-due-to-linux-videodev-h-no-such-file-or-direct)

Answer (score 1):

Since the issue is a missing `linux/videodev.h`, try installing a package which [provides it](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=linux%2Fvideodev.h&mode=exactfilename&suite=trusty&arch=any):

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-i686-linux-android
```